# How can I get the user's input to be checked if it exists in the data

Tags: python, function, dictionary

I got my code to work by allowing user to store the username and password in the dictionary. After I ask the user to login and then the function login() goes through the dictionary to see if it exists. If it exists the user in welcomed, else user tries again. Here's my code.

```
data = {}
def store(stor, username, password):
    stor[username] = password   

def create():
    for i in range(2):
        user = raw_input("Username: ")
        pas = raw_input("Password: ")
        while user in data:
            print("Try Again")
            user = raw_input("Username: ")
            pas = raw_input("Password: ")
        store(data,user, pas)
        print (data)

def login():
    create()
    print("")
    loguser = raw_input("Please Enter Username: ")
    logpass = raw_input("Please Enter Password: ")
    if loguser and logpass in data:
        print ("Welcome!")
    else:
        print ("Try Again!)
    store(data, loguser, logpass)

login()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the line,

```
if loguser and logpass in data:
```

to,

```
if (loguser,logpass) in data.items():
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem should be in the user authentication line.

```
if loguser and logpass in data:
```

This line checks whether the value of loguser is True and whether logpass is in the keys of the dictionary data.

You should change this line to:

```
if loguser in data and data[loguser] == logpass:
```

to check if loguser is in the dictionary and if the value of data[loguser], which is the passwd, is equal to logpass.